# Actionmailer on Boolean Value True

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have a Quotes Model and i have added a Actionmailer in the Update - Controller.

I would like the Actionmailer to only go off when the Accepted (Boolean) is ticked.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if @user.active == true
          UserMailer.active_user_notice_email(@user).deliver
 end
```

Sorted it Out